# Why can't I reuse a pipe to communicate with multiple child processes?

Tags: unix, pipe

If I have a parent process which has `n` child processes, why am I not able to use one pipe to send the parent's pid to all the child processes? This is briefly covered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870006/do-i-have-to-make-a-new-pipe-for-every-pair-of-processes-in-c),
but I feel it's not explained too clearly.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void){

    int n;

    printf("How many child processes would you like to create?");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    pid_t pid, child, ppid, pidout;
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        pid = fork();
        switch(pid){
        
            case -1:
                printf("error forking at index %i", i);
                exit(1);
                
            case 0: 
                close(fd[1]);
                child = getpid();
                read(fd[0], &pidout, 4);
                printf("\nNode : %i\nMy pid is : %i\nMy parent's pid is : %i\n\n", i, child, pidout);
                exit(0);
                
            default:    
                close(fd[0]);
                ppid = getpid();
                write(fd[1], &ppid, 4);
                if (!i){
                    printf("\nNode : %i, My pid is : %i\n\n", i, ppid);
                }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            wait();
    }

}
```

Here, I attempt to reuse the same pipe to send the data from parent to child, but the pipe is breaking after the parent's pid is sent to the first child. I understand that the way of solving this is by having `n-1` pipes: one for each communication. However, I don't understand *why* this code doesn't work. Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I like using `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` and `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` to avoid "magic numbers". I also don't like how you use 4 as a magic number - isn't it supposed to be `sizeof(int)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you `close()` the read end of the pipe in the parent too early and when other forked childs try to read from it, they get `EBADF`. you should **always** check return value of `read()` and `write()`.

If you move `close(fd[0]);` at the end, after the `wait()` calls, the code should works as expected.

here a working rewrite of the code to illustrate what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
        int n;

        printf("How many child processes would you like to create?");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid number\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


        pid_t pid, child, ppid, pidout;
        int fd[2];
        if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
                perror("pipe");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                pid = fork();
                switch (pid) {
                case -1:
                        printf("error forking at index %i", i);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                case 0: /* child */
                        close(fd[1]);
                        child = getpid();
                        if (read(fd[0], &pidout, sizeof(pidout)) < 0) {
                                perror("read");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                        printf("Node: %i My pid is: %i My parent's pid is: %i\n", i, child, pidout);
                        close(fd[0]);
                        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

                default: /* parent */
                        ppid = getpid();
                        if (write(fd[1], &ppid, sizeof(ppid)) < 0) {
                                perror("write");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                        if (i == 0)
                                printf("\nParent, My pid is: %i\n\n", ppid);
                }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                wait(NULL);

        /* close pipe in the parent at the end, to avoid bad file descriptors
         * in the forked children */
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
}
```

Comment: OP is closing the read end of the pipe in the parent the write end of the pipe in the children, so that's probably not it.

Comment: @einpoklum when it forks children again, at the next iteration, **after the first close**, it will get bad read file descriptor in the children

Comment: Ah of course! That makes sense. Just to make sure I've got this right: I couldn't use the same logic to communicate between children nodes with only one pipe, right? In this case, I would have to create n-1 pipes? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @iaskdumbstuff yes, probably having one pipe per child is best/easier solution and will free you from synchronization problems that arise when you use a single pipe with multiple children.

Answer (score 2):

(Caveat: I'm not a pipe and Unix IPC expert.)

What you're probably seeing is the intended behavior of pipes, which is that what goes through the pipe comes out on the other side and doesn't just stay there for others to observe. One process writes, another process reads - the pipe doesn't retain all of that data, and gets cleared.

Perhaps a different system call, which allows peaking at the buffer of the pipe without clearing it, could work - although that doesn't sound like an elegant solution. Another possible approach would be setting up a "poster board" inn the form of an interprocess shared memory area which the parent process writes to and the children can read.

**Edit:** You also have an issue with premature closing of the read-end of the pipe before creating all children. See @MarcoLucidi's answer.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. However, I believed that in my code, the parent wrote the data to the pipe at every iteration. Is this not the case?

Comment: @iaskdumbstuff : Nobody guarantees each process will get its desired piece of written information; it's quite likely a single process will get all of it, or a few processes will get some, etc. Anyway, always always always check your system and library call return values for errors!

Comment: I see. But if this were the case wouldn't I expect to see different child processes to recieve the parent's pid at different executions? When I execute, the first child recieves the data, but all the others recieve 0. I should have maybe mentioned that I'm getting a broken pipe after using the pipe the first time. I'll add edit that in the post.

Comment: @iaskdumbstuff: Marco has your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant documentation to read includes (for Linux) [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [pipe(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [fifo(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [dup2(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [close(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html)

When [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) fails, you probably want to use [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to understand why it has failed. And most other system calls can fail too, and you need to read its documentation, and handle their failure cases.

### You certainly need to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

For Unix systems which are not Linux (e.g. [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/)), you should refer to their documentation.

If your C compiler is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), I recommend reading its documentation then using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` when compiling, and learn to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

If you are not familiar with C, please read the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book and refer to websites such as [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website.

Looking into *existing* [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) projects coded in C (for example on [github.com](https://github.com/) or [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/)) should be inspirational.

You might be interested by projects such as [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).